# Why can't I view or add SQL and Network Performance Counters in Performance Monitor?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, performance-monitoring

I'm trying to add the below Performance Counters to a user-defined data collector set in a Performance Monitor on Windows Server 2012 R2.  I can see them when I dump them to a file (eg typeperf -q -o "C:\Temp\counters.txt"), but I'm not able to see them among the Available Counters of the Data Collection properties.  SQL Server Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) is installed on this machine, and it's running on VMWare (version to follow). I'm told I have admin rights and someone with full rights isn't able to see them either.  Why can't I see them?

```
SQL Statistics: Batch Requests/sec
SQL Statistics: SQL Compilations/sec
SQL Statistics: SQL Recompilations/sec
SQL Server: Wait Statistics
SQL Server: Buffer Manager Buffer Cache Hit Ratio
SQL Server: Wait Statistics Page IO latch waits
SQL Server:Buffer Manager Page Life Expectancy
Network: % Network Utilization
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the command-line tool typeperf.  You can use it to extract all

```
typeperf -q -o all_counters.txt
```

I pulled the counters I wanted from all_counters.txt and then I used the below to capture these pointers into a log file

```
typeperf -cf flip_perf_counters.txt -f tsv -si 05 -o log_file.txt
```